# full background image is not rending properly in a div

Tags: css, html

I am using a full background image in my div, but when resizing the window it is not resizing properly from left and right, I do not want to use `position:fixed` because it is creating issues for me.

Kindly help, how can I fix this issue, the image should resize perfectly as per window size (resize).

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="col-md-3"></div>
           <div class="col-md-9">
                 <div class="loginbg"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

**css:**
.loginbg{
background: url("../../images/TalexAuthbg3.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    z-index: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100vh;
    background-position:100%;
}
```

I want to render a full background image within the `.loginbg` div but it is not rendering properly.

Comment: Can you make a working example in snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: use `background-size:contain`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `background-size: contain` if you want the full image to show at every window size, because of `background-size: cover` crops the image to fit the window size without disturbing its aspect ratio.

```css
.loginbg{
background: url("https://longstoryshortdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/mc-saatchi-hero-home.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    z-index: 0;
    background-size: contain;
    height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="col-md-3"></div>
           <div class="col-md-9">
                 <div class="loginbg"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```